# Express: Infinite loading spinner in Chrome

Tags: node.js, express

Given the most basic Express example:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World');
})

app.listen(3000)
```

the page renders correctly and completely, but the tab loading spinner never completes and Chrome 38 is perpetually "Waiting for localhost...". Chrome Dev Tools -> Network indicate no pending/incomplete requests.

Is there something additional needed to complete the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the lack of a favicon. To solve, use the `serve-favicon` module:

```
var express = require('express')
var favicon = require('serve-favicon')
var app = express()

app.use(favicon());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World');
})

app.listen(3000)
```